# Isabelle: maximum value in a vector

Tags: vector, max, isabelle

I would like to find the maximum in a vector of natural numbers. Vector (i.e., ‘vec’), however, is a different type than Set or List. I thought about several ideas that did not work, like leveling or lifting the type of vec or the definition of a recursive function.

What solution do you suggest to get the maximum value in a vector?

```
(*
IMPORTS:
  "~~/src/HOL/Algebra/Ring"
  "~~/src/HOL/Library/Numeral_Type"
  "~~/src/HOL/Library/Permutations"
  "~~/src/HOL/Library/Polynomial"
  "~~/src/HOL/Big_Operators"

 vec (VECTOR) is from Finite_Cartesian_Product
 degree is from Polynomial
 Max is from Big_Operators
*)

(* The problem is that "Max" from Big_Operators is not working on vectors! *)
definition maxdeg:: "('a::zero poly)^'n ⇒ nat" where "maxdeg v = Max(χ i . degree(v$i))"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum operator `Max` has type `'a set => 'a`, i.e., retrieves the maximum element from a (finite) set. Vectors (type `(a, b) vec`) are essentially functions from indices to entries with abstraction written as `χ i. _` and application as `v $ _`.

You now want to get the maximum value in the range of a vector. With the above in mind, you can use the `range` function and spell out the function application on vectors:

```
 maxdeg v = Max (range (%j. (χ i. degree (v $ i)) $ j))
```

This can be simplified to

```
 maxdeg v = Max (range (%i. degree (v $ i)))
```

If you just want the maximum entry of a vector without mapping degree over vector first, the following works (where `op $ v` is the eta-contraction of `%j. v $ j`):

```
 maxvec v = Max (range (op $ v))
```